# How to pass a list to initial frame in swing

Tags: java, swing

```
public Lab7(File file) {
    List<Item> items = null;
    try {
        items = InventoryReader.read(file);
    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, use the default.
            }
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(items); // THIS IS WHERE I HAVE TROUBLE
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Background: I set the constructor of MainFrame to accept a list. How do I do this in the main() of my application?

I get the error:

Cannot refer to a non-final variable "items" inside an inner class defined in a different method

The error is in the  `MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(items)`  I can't seem to pass MainFrame class the items variable... Why is that?

How do I pass this variable into into the MainFrame frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices....

### Choice one...

Make the `items` list final so it is accessiable from within the `Runnable`s context...

```
public Lab7(File file) {
    final List<Item> items = null; // Make the items final...
    try {
        items = InventoryReader.read(file);
    } catch (ApplicationException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, use the default.
            }
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(items); // THIS IS WHERE I HAVE TROUBLE
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### Choice two...

Move the `items` list into the `Runnable`s context

```
public Lab7(File file) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {
            // Load the items within the content of the runnable...
            List<Item> items = null;
            try {
                items = InventoryReader.read(file);
            } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, use the default.
            }
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(items); // THIS IS WHERE I HAVE TROUBLE
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List<Item> items` needs to be declared final.

You are accessing a non-final local-variable from the inner class that extends `Runnable`, which is not allowed.

Comment: But I'm populating that thing via the "items = InventoryReader.read(file)"

Comment: Trying moving the declaration, and everything after the catch inside the try-block. And make items final.

Comment: Or, use another field: `final List<Item> _items = items`. Then, you would use `_items` as the list argument.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `List<Item> items` as a member variable and use your constructor to initialize your list.

```
public class Lab7 {

    private List<Item> items;

    public Lab7(File file) {
        try {
           items = InventoryReader.read(file);
        } catch (ApplicationException e) {
           LOG.error(e.getMessage());
           return;
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, use the default.
            }
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(items);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```